# Open XML SDK: Adding images with border (C#)

Tags: c#, image, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I easily managed to add images to a word-document using this manual [How to: Insert a picture into a word processing document](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/open-xml/how-to-insert-a-picture-into-a-word-processing-document), but I can´t figure out how to add a border to all those images.

I guess this post might help [Open XML SDK adding gradient border to all drawings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52184296/open-xml-sdk-adding-gradient-border-to-all-drawings), but I can´t make it work.

Any suggestions? Tanks!

**Edit:**
I managed to get kind of a result with the following code, where I integrated the outline1 part from the second link into the element part from the manual. However, the outline ist now blue and has a gradient:

```
.
.
.

new PIC.ShapeProperties(
    new A.Transform2D(
        new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
        new A.Extents() { Cx = widthEmus, Cy = heightEmus }),
    new A.PresetGeometry(
        new A.AdjustValueList()
    )
    { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle },

    new A.Outline(new A.GradientFill(
        new A.GradientStopList(
            new A.GradientStop(
                new A.SchemeColor(
                    new A.LuminanceModulation() { Val = 5000 },
                    new A.LuminanceOffset() { Val = 95000 }
                )
                { Val = A.SchemeColorValues.Accent1 }
            )
            { Position = 0 },
            new A.GradientStop(
                new A.SchemeColor(
                    new A.LuminanceModulation() { Val = 45000 },
                    new A.LuminanceOffset() { Val = 55000 }
                )
                { Val = A.SchemeColorValues.Accent1 }
            )
            { Position = 74000 },
            new A.GradientStop(
                new A.SchemeColor(
                    new A.LuminanceModulation() { Val = 45000 },
                    new A.LuminanceOffset() { Val = 55000 }
                )
                { Val = A.SchemeColorValues.Accent1 }
            )
            { Position = 83000 },
            new A.GradientStop(
                new A.SchemeColor(
                    new A.LuminanceModulation() { Val = 30000 },
                    new A.LuminanceOffset() { Val = 70000 }
                )
                { Val = A.SchemeColorValues.Accent1 }
            )
            { Position = 100000 }),
        new A.LinearGradientFill()
        {
            Angle = 5400000,
            Scaled = true
        }
    ))))
)
{ Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })

.
.
.
```

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Hey @sander, thanks for your fast response. I actually just managed to make it work a little, but the border is now blue and has a colour gradient (see edit). Probably because I blindly copied the code from the second link without understanding it...

Comment: It seems you are adding gradients, so I suggest you experiment with the code a bit to get a clear understanding of what it does. You are 90% there :)

Comment: I will do so :) Thank you

Comment: Simplest way to solve a question such as this is to create a simple document with exactly what you need, then open it in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool...

Comment: @CindyMeister. That helped a lot! :) Thanks